# organise pandas data frame like yahoo finance multiple stock dataframe

Tags: pandas, database, dataframe, group-by, yahoo-api

I'm trying to organize my pandas data frame like the one we get from yahoo finance data frame of multiple stock symbols with OHLCV. how to achieve that.[image]

i tried.

```
df = df[['Name','datetime','open','high','low','close','volume']]
df.set_index(['Name', 'datetime'], inplace=True)
df = df.astype(float)

and got the following output.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends what need. If need all columns in `MultiIndex` in columns:

```
df1 = df.astype(float).unstack(0).swaplevel(0,1,axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
```

If need processing only one column, e.g. `open`:

```
df2 = df.astype(float)['open'].unstack(0)
```

Comment: i need open high low close volume but these both code didint worked

Comment: @KamalJeet - But why missing columns `open high low close volume` in expected ouput?

Comment: while downloading it from yahoofinance the default output is adj price for multiple symbols.

Comment: @KamalJeet - why missing columns `open high low close volume` in expected ouput?

Comment: i need columns open high low close volume

Comment: @KamalJeet - why missing columns `open high low close volume` in expected ouput? It means expected ouput is something else what need?

Comment: @KamalJeet - I see 10 rows in input data in question (black pic). Expected ouput is something else, not from data from black pic. So no idea, what need. Solution is create expected ouput exactly from data in question, e.g. from first and fifth rows. Thanks.

Comment: open high low close volume is expected and symbol name as column header

Comment: need same as white pic symbol name in top and other data below i have multiple symbols in the dataframe

Comment: @KamalJeet - Unfortunately data not match. So no idea what need.

Comment: @jezrael- hi that is because i had indexed datetime and name the index name removes the same symbol name from below .